# Octave script no longer runs in Crontab

Tags: cron, octave

I have some crontabs that run various Octave script files thus:

```
*/10 * * * 1-5 /usr/local/bin/octave "/path/to/octave/script.m" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

which, up until a few days ago, were working as they should but have, for some reason I cannot find, now stopped working. The script files download data via an API and then append to existing files. I don't believe it's a problem with the cronjob or cron daemon or such like as almost identical R script crontabs,

```
*/10 * * * 1-5 /usr/bin/Rscript "/path/to/R/script.R" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

which also download and append data, are still working as they should. The apparent failure is just for the call to run the Octave scripts.

I've done some obvious checks such as:

- check that the files are still executable (they are)
- check that symbolic links from /usr/local/bin/octave are still intact (they are)
- check that the script files can still be run manually from Octave (they can)
- grep CRON /var/log/syslog appears to show that everything is working, i.e. I get the following output

  Oct  5 00:01:01 username CRON[12110]: (username) CMD (/usr/local/bin/octave "/path/to/octave/script.m" >/dev/null 2>&1)

What else can I do to track down the source of this problem?

Comment: Instead of redirecting all output to `/dev/null`, redirect it to a file. Then look at the contents of the file to see what error messages are shown.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Cris's comment to direct output to a file I was able to find the source of this problem, which was a recent edit to the .octaverc start up file for Octave.

I had recently added a line to express a preference for a particular graphics toolkit and this was the first line in the .octaverc file. When Octave was being called by the crontab job this line was throwing an error. By moving this entry to be the last line of .octaverc, plus changing the crontab to use the command line version of Octave thus:

```
*/10 * * * 1-5 /usr/local/bin/octave-cli "/path/to/octave/script.m" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

the called "/path/to/octave/script.m" now runs as expected. I am still getting an error message thus:

```
error: graphics_toolkit: fltk toolkit is not available
error: called from
graphics_toolkit at line 88 column 5
/home/user/.octaverc at line 3 column 1
```

but since the command line interface doesn't require a GUI and the addpaths and such like in .octaverc are run before the error is thrown, the running of the script isn't interuptted.